# odoo qweb report current user lang

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I am creating the report which can be translated to current user language. so I tried the following code. Report is working but the language to translate is always the `partner_id` of model (`stock.picking`), But I want the report to be translated to current logged user lang.

report translation is as below:

```
<template id="report_print_recvng_wkst">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
            <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'partner_id.lang', 'wms_report.report_recvngwkst_document')"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

I also tried putting `user.lang` , `lang` or `env.user.lang`, but I get the error that stock.picking do not have user.lang etc.

Also, is there a way to debug in xml file, I mean how can I see the env object in report

Comment: Odoo translate reports in logged user language, so you don't need to specify that.

Comment: Hi WalR, the report Lang is not changed based on current logged user, but if the partner_id is same as logged user it changes. I think it changes based on partner_id not current logged user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default behavior is that, in report partner language is set, report is generated in partner's language (partner which is set there in record).

And if you want to update that scenario then you need to do such other thing like `partner_id.lang` should be replaced by `request.env.user.partner_id.lang`

```
<template id="report_print_recvng_wkst">
    <t t-call="report.html_container">
        <t t-foreach="doc_ids" t-as="doc_id">
            <t t-raw="translate_doc(doc_id, doc_model, 'request.env.user.partner_id.lang', 'wms_report.report_recvngwkst_document')"/>
        </t>
    </t>
</template>
```

Comment: Hi Emipro, i get following error: " stock.picking" object don't have doc.user.partner_id

Comment: instead user we need to write `request.env.user`, I have updated answer, try this.

Comment: Thanks Emipro, it works, also env.user.partner_id.lang can be used. Thanks